# Tic tac toe javascript. Make it so X and 0 can only be pressed once, not overwrite eachother

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

How can I make it so that X and 0 cant overwrite and only be pressed once on every space?

I tried `if(input.value = "") return` but that did not work unless I put it in the wrong place.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
let clicks = 1;
for (let input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    input.value = ("0")
    const id = evt.target.id;
    const buttonNr = id[1];
    if (clicks % 2 === 0) {
      if (input.value = "X")
        console.log(`Player X pressed ${buttonNr}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Player 0 pressed ${buttonNr}`);
    }
    clicks++
  })
}
```

Comment: [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) accepts a third argument where you can set `once` to `true`. Alternatively, why not just check if the cell has already been clicked, using some kind of Array, Map, Set, or other data structure to keep track of cells?

Comment: @SebastianSimon didn't knew about the once in the object. Always thought it was used for capturing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
let clicks = 1;
for (let input of inputs) {
    input.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
        // Make sure input is empty
        if(evt.target.value == "") {
            // Increment "clicks"; check if (clicks modulo 2) == 0;
            // if true place an "X" otherwise place an "O".
            evt.target.value = (clicks++ % 2 == 0) ? "X" : "O";
        }
    })
}
```